# How to get the REMOTE_PORT (the client port) in Python running at IIS 7.5? REMOTE_PORT server variable cannot be found!

Tags: python, windows, iis-7, cgi

Hey. I'm coding a cgi in Python, running on an IIS 7.5 web server, on Windows. I would like to get the tcp port (usually was the server environment variable REMOTE_PORT) from which the client is connecting to it.

I've tried to look up all the way throuhout the keys as in os.environ.keys() and I can get the user IP address, his browser, platform, but no remote port available.

I have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed already.

Could anyone please figure out what's happening or a way to make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Googling suggests people with ASP.NET and PHP solutions have similar problems and that since [IIS 5.0 that variable hasn't been available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319083).  I get the impression you have to call a routine called GetServerVariable() to retrieve it.  That routine sounds like it's available through various libraries, which you may be able to use as-is or lift code from:

- [PyISAPIe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyISAPIe/1.0.3)
- [isapi-wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/)
- [pywin32's isapi module](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/html/isapi/doc/isapi.html) (note, those pywin32 docs can be browsed only in a local copy apparently, but you can read that page to learn more)

There are probably others.